# asp.net web API change JSON date format to UTC

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

How can I change JSON `date` format to `UTC` automatically?

now when I get data from server included dates, it returns as local zone date. I know I can change `dates` in the server with this code to `UTC`:

```
var date = DateTime.Now.ToUniversal();
```

but I need to make it auto.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `Json.NET` preserves the time zone. You can override this by setting the `DateTimeZoneHandling` property:

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
```

Call this from your `Application_Start` method, defined in the `Global.asax`.

You can find more information is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization).